# Where are policies in the AzureAd B2C tenant

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have an existing Azure AD B2C tenant, in which the main blade has a policies section as shown below. 
However when I create a new tenant, I dont see polciies section in the blade on the left.

Existing tenant

[image: Existing tenant]

New tenant

[image: New tenant]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the new UI of Azure AD B2C. 
the basic policies are rebranded as User Flow. 
If you see blade in the new tenant, you will see User Flow option.

Also click on the welcome link in the tenant overview blade to understand the changes. 
Soon all the new and old tenants will get the new experience.

If you want to use the old portal for sometime, please go to http://aka.ms/b2coldportal and choose your tenant from tenant selection blade.